# ¿Cómo no repetir valor dentro de foreach en php?

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando un slider, elavoro un foreach para las imágenes que mostrare, el problema que tengo es que el primer div que contendra la primera imagen tiene la clase active, ya el segundo no debería ir, quisiera saber la manera que ya no se repita para el segundo div, de antemano gracias.
Este es mi código:

```
<?php

        function mostrarProyectosDetalle()
        {
         $idProy = $_POST['idProy'];

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM imagenproy where idProyectos = $idProy");

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
           }

                 $listaproy = mostrarProyectosDetalle();
                 echo '
                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <div class="carousel-inner">';
                            foreach ($listaproy as $key => $value) {
                              echo '
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/imagenes/galeriaImg/' . $value['rutaImagenProy'] . '" alt="First slide"> </div>';
                                }
                                echo '    
                                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una forma rápida de validar de que sea el primero es usar una variable que te esté contando los pasos del for. Cuando esta cambie sabrás que ya no es la primera vuelta o, en tu caso, la primera imagen. La parte de tu ciclo quedaría:

```
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($listaproy as $key => $value) {
    if($counter == 0){
      echo '<div class="carousel-item active"><img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/imagenes/galeriaImg/' . $value['rutaImagenProy'] . '" alt="First slide"> </div>';
    }else{
      echo '<div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/imagenes/galeriaImg/' . $value['rutaImagenProy'] . '" alt="slide"> </div>';
    }
    $counter++;
  }
```